# ios - compile error: redefinition of label openURL

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{        
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"aaa"]) 
        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.firstwebsite.com"];

    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"abc"]) 
        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"];

    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"xyz"]) 
        openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.anothersite.com"];

    return YES;
}
```

and on the second and third uses of openURL I get a compile error: `redefinition of label openURL`

Any idea why that happens and how to resolve it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you should be using the "`UIApplication`" method [`openURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a).

In other words, instead of doing:

```
openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.anothersite.com"];
```

do

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.anothersite.com"]];
```